# When I need to explicitly define the type of a const?

Tags: typescript

Basically, I want to know if it's right or wrong to explicitly define the type of consts, for example:

Here I have a const which it's type shows when I simply put the mouse over, typescript got the type automatically:

[image]

but, can I explicit show the type like this?

```
const tasksRef: CollectionReference<DocumentData> = collection(db, "tasks");
```

My question is, is this wrong, right or unnecessary?

In my opinion, it helps me to learn about the types, in that case, about Firebase's types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong, it's matter of opinion and code styling. However, there are good arguments for **avoiding** explicitly declaring your types.

The effective TypeScript project has a nice chapter on [explicitly annotating inferable types](https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/04/28/avoid-inferable/), and why it is considered a poor style.

My own personal opinion is that it makes your code harder to read and since most IDEs will show you the variable type when you mouse over it, an explicit declaration is redundant and noisy.

Still, it's one of those styling questions where's no 100% right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, default to allowing TypeScript to infer or use the correct typings without explicitly defining them.

Examples where typings don't need to be explicitly stated:

```js
function createString() : string{
    return "hello!"; 
}


const a = createString(); // const a: string

const b = "hello"; //const b: "hello"

const c = {
    foo: "bar"
}; 
// const c: {
//     foo: string;
// }
```

Examples of where some assertions/coercions may be required:

```js
/**
 * For example, this function is from a library that does not have typings
 */
function returnsAny() : any {
    return "hello"; 
}

const d1 = returnsAny(); //const d1: any
const d2 = returnsAny() as string; //const d2: string


function acceptsStringLiterals(value: "foo" | "bar") {

}

const e1 = "foo"; 
acceptsStringLiterals(e1); // This is fine. 

const e2 = {
    value: "foo"
}

acceptsStringLiterals(e2.value); // This is not, because `value` has widened to `string` 

const e3 = {
    value: "foo"
} as {value: "foo" | "bar"}; 
// const e3: {
//     value: "foo" | "bar";
// }

acceptsStringLiterals(e3.value);

const e4 = {
    value: "foo"
} as const

// const e4: {
//     readonly value: "foo";
// }

acceptsStringLiterals(e4.value);

const e5 = {
    value: "foo"
} satisfies {value: "foo" | "bar"}; // The new 'satifies'operator behaves nicer than 'as const' coercions
// const e5: {
//     value: "foo";
// }
acceptsStringLiterals(e5.value);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=69&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQZSimMAcwAoBKRALkQGd9CiBvAKETcXShBSQCIALNABshcAIS8A3ImYBfZgogI6iDIgC8ydFlz1i5aQHpDyZVFXU6BYorOIARhsQDhoqYmNKwK+9Rci4XltvcwgnFnZEYDg4P3sMFCDZaWZjUxDkahY0yOjY2j0iSVSTeQVDACoK1grEADE4FEQ0AA8MAFsAByE0ABpEKH4YGijwaHgkYaiUOHbVRCEYexQEgE8B-ixEABM4NBGwOHNNgDc0AdXOhhoaw2ZQSFgEDjQuHhoAQTBV8ipVb8QEXYnG4fEEAXccmCKm2AEYnCD3l8fmQjIYvDDYdQMN9mBjzNsAEwI16gz7fX4YEZWBho-E7QmWQoKe5jJ5IDAQCBoTpQGh4axEAAyMGwKyENBIJwwQhAaD8eV4iAAPs54okKCwoXi7Gh4ZpeIqUpzubz+YURWKZZK9aiPCYACpDEZTYCENAAOhkOoyaGJmiBbGlsvlzkV2pNPL5AoYlrQ4pthI9wbldrSTqmU0OUH69jQEAwIBo5wABim0CXEJsRgB3GDbNBgNDbAZwRAlmnESvQ8xoADM4VY7HLCpiSVUI0YI7DY5VaoSvGSMjS9P7WRKkUQ08Ns9VvHVUg3ZUjZpjxDjCZI-eTMtTxR9KjQABZB5Ft+HZBP0nRyiZV0-1xyYFMF2MAhHWd8x2KNJjy5KNzUFC9rSvJ8bxDVEe2aABWV9h1vUMd0CORaCwYY3X2QFIMCOd9wXJd00ERAmxrRAAHIaFI8iaFYuBOnjLBGgcNBTgosAYG5JpBhxNiqW-KBWNMeMIAmG4V11LDAJMN98NHQJoNKZgT2jC1RX4iUrywtC7xZZggA)

Generally, I find that type widening on strings, and usage of functions with untyped signatures is where I will need to make assertions/coercions.

Also, there are plenty of scenarios where TypeScript is simply not smart enough to infer the correct type, and so coercing types, saying 'I know better' is often warranted there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it doesn't matter and is just an issue of style. One situation where it matters is in a public API: if your library exports a constant, then it is better to give it an explicit type rather than an inferred type, because the inferred type might change in a future version of Typescript, or it might be different in an older version.

Users of your library may write their own code which depends on your constant having a particular type, and their code may break if your constant is inferred as having a different type than the one which was inferred when you wrote it. This applies in both directions:

```js
// breaks if YOUR_CONSTANT has a weaker type than expected
foo(YOUR_CONSTANT);

let bar = YOUR_CONSTANT;
// breaks if YOUR_CONSTANT has a stronger type than expected,
// because `somethingElse()` may not have that stronger type
if(baz) { bar = somethingElse(); }
```

Therefore, public constants exported by libraries should generally have explicit type annotations to avoid this problem.